# Break Even Point

Tags: finance, economics

Suppose that x thousand units of a product will be sold when the price is p(x) = 50 - 1.25x dollars per unit and the cost of producing x thousand units is C(x) = 20x + 100 thousand dollars.

a) What levels of production result in the company just breaking even?

Would this be setting p(x) = C(x)?

b) What price per unit would would result in the company just breaking even?

Comment: Rather than assigning your homework to math.stackexchange.com, you should just ask the questions you want to hear answers too; e.g. just ask whether setting $p(x)=C(x)$. If you have trouble actually solving your problem at that point, only then should you ask a question about what your problem is (again, asking a question you want to hear the answer to, rather than just assigning your homework). I expect if you have trouble, all you really need to hear is the translation from the word problem into an algebra problem, rather than help actually solving the algebra problem.

Comment: I just wanted to give as much information as I could.

Comment: Your costs per $x$-thousand units is $C(x)$ thousand dollars  so the costs per unit are $\frac{C(x)}{1000x}$ thousand dollars. This are   $1000 \frac{C(x)}{1000x}$ dollars. This is equal to $\frac{C(x)}{x}$ dollars per unit. The price per unit is $p(x)$ dollars.

Answer (score 3):

If "breaking even" means you spend as much as you receive, then you need to set those quantities equal.

There are (at least) two ways you could measure this:

> cost per item = price per item
>
> total cost = total sales

In your problem, $p(x)$ is the price per item, but $C(x)$ is the total cost, so you're comparing apples to oranges: note that looking at the units tells you this, since "dollars per item" and "thousands of dollars" are different kinds of units.

Instead, you're going to either have to compute total sales, or cost per item.

(strictly speaking, breaking even means "total cost = total sales", but it's not hard to see that if "cost per item = price per item" that you must also have "total cost = total sales")

(also, take care that, if you get in a situation where you're comparing "dollars" to "thousands of dollars" that you do an appropriate unit conversion)

Comment: When I set p(x) = C(x) I get -2.353 which doesn't make sense. What am I found wrong?

Comment: @Jesus: Ah, I misread, let me make a correction. (incidentally, there should be another inequation $x \geq 0$ in the problem, so if $p(x)=C(x)$ were correct, that would simply mean that the system has no solutions, so breaking even would be impossible)

Answer (score 0):

The break-even point (BEP) in terms of (Thousand) Unit Sales $x$ can be directly computed in terms of Total Revenue $r(x)=x\times p(x)$ (price $\times$ quantity) and Total Costs $c(x)$ as the quantity at which the profit $\pi(x)=r(x)-c(x)=0$, that is
$$
p(x)x-c(x) = (50 - 1.25x)x-(20x + 100)=0\quad\Longrightarrow \quad x_1=4,\,x_2=20
$$
so the profit will be positive if the production is beetwen $x_1$ and $x_2$:
$$
\pi(x)\ge 0 \quad\text{for }x_1\le x\le x_2
$$
So the prices at the break-even points are $p_1=p(x_1)=45$ and $p_2=p(x_2)=25$.
[image]